# Prevent "if there are problems with how this message is displayed" on Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2013

I send HTML report emails to customers, which display nicely on most email clients. When displayed in Outlook 2013, the following message is sometimes displayed:

> if there are problems with how this message is displayed, click here to view it in a web browser.

I would like to get rid of this message. [This post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/trying-to-get-rid-of-message-if-there-are-problems/5dc9d5d1-1234-42f4-a381-dfe846e4f9b1) suggests removing all `thead` and `tbody` tags from the message (there aren't any in my HTML code) and replace inline CSS with embedded CSS, which I can't do because other mail clients have problems with non-inline CSS.

Are there any known ways to prevent this message from showing?

Comment: You might need to post your code...

Comment: [Here is another suggestion](http://www.emailsignature.eu/phpBB2/how-to-get-view-in-browser-link-in-outlook-2010-t1550.html) which suggests to add `<span style="padding: 0px;"></span>` at the bottom of the HTML email body.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found that by adding the following to the `head` section of the page, that the message is not displayed.

```
<meta name="ProgId" content="Word.Document">
```

I learned this by saving a nearly blank word document as HTML and selectively removing bloat over and over until I narrowed it down to this. In my case, the email was being sent using TSQL in SQL Server 2008 R2 via the `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` function.

Comment: I did all three things: got rid of any `thead` and `tbody`, added that "Word.Document" meta tag and added the `<span style="padding: 0px;"></span>` at the end of my HTML body. I don't know which actually worked, but now my sent emails don't trigger the Outlook 2013 warning anymore.

Comment: This solved my issue without having to remove thead and tbody tags from my markup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Uwe Keim (above) and his solution (from a page that doesn't exist anymore):

add

```
<span style="padding: 0px;"></span>
```

to the bottom of the email, right before the closing body tag.
That's it. No need to get rid of all the deprecated stuff (that Mailchimp always adds)!